# update and set value with max()+1 problems

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a row and set the shipment_number with `max()+1`. The reason for this is the table already has a `auto_increment` on another column named id. From the first query i'm getting the `max(shipment_number)` and in the next query iam incrementing with `+1`. But iam getting an error..

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'commercial_sales_custpo_process' for update in FROM clause

Anyone pls help me with this query.

```
$max = "SELECT MAX(shipment_number) FROM commercial_sales_custpo_process WHERE 
tender_id='$tender_id' AND id='$id'";

$query1="UPDATE commercial_sales_custpo_process set shipment_number = ($max+1) WHERE 
tender_id='$tender_id' AND id='$id'";
mysql_query($query1) or die ("Error in query: $query1");
```

Comment: try to incre before entering into the query. `$var=$max+1;` and assign this variable `$var`  to  update query. also recommend to start with `mysqli` http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: why not AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: If there is already an auto_increment why do you need this?  It can be calculated when data is selected without having to deal with the problems that arise when 2 session run this concurrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Auto_Increment` is not available , simply use `UPDATE..JOIN` :

```
UPDATE commercial_sales_custpo_process t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(shimpent_number) + 1 as max_ship 
            FROM commercial_sales_custpo_process) s
 SET t.shipment_number = s.max_ship
WHERE t.tender_id='$tender_id' AND t.id='$id'
```

Comment: No problem mate @SanjuMenon